# Packet loss and delay with MAC address level communication

Tags: networking

How to find packet loss and delay between two systems when both are communicating with MAC address. Here client and server using the half duplex communication, is there any tool to measure these two characteristics directly.

PS: In IP based protocol we can use ping or tcptrace to measure these two characters, seraching for similar way on MAC address protocol communication.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there isn't a defined 'ping' "application" for layer 2 - there's no standard as to what the echo request and echo reply would look like.  You would need to write the software yourself to send and get back these packets.  Don't forget that you would need to intercept these packets at a somewhat low level, because the network card driver is going to discard them because they're not IP, or IPX, or Appletalk... they're something else completely.